# Proving an expectation is finite and convergence to the expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P$) such that $E(X_{n}^{2}) \leq c$ for some constant $c$. Suppose further that $X_{n}\rightarrow X$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$. Prove $E(X)$ is finite, and show that $E(X_{n}) \rightarrow E(X)$

I haven't been able to figure out either part of this problem (showing finiteness and showing $E(X_n) = E(X)$. I have some idea about what to do for the second part, like use the $E(X_n^{2}) \leq c$ bound, and maybe try to use Chebyshev's inequality, but I have not made any progress. I wrote the variance in terms of $E(X)$ and tried to use Chebyshev and it just got messy. Markov's inequality doesn't lead me anywhere either.

I am wondering if someone can assist me with this problem please

Answer (score 1):

By Fatou's Lemma $EX^{2} <\infty$ and this makes $E(X_n-X)^{2}$ bounded. Now $E|X_n-X| =E|X_n-X|I_{|X_n-X| >M} +E|X_n-X|I_{|X_n-X| \leq M}$. The first term does not  exceed $\frac 1 {M} E(X_n-X)^{2}$. Use the hypothesis to choose $M$ such that  this is less than $\epsilon$ for all $n$.  For the second term apply Bounded Convergence Theorem.

I have used the following: $E|X_n-X|I_{|X_n-X| >M} \leq \sqrt {E(X_n-X)^{2}} \sqrt {P(|X_n-X>M)}$ by Holder's inequality  and $P(|X_n-X|>M) \leq \frac 1 {M^{2}} (E(X_n-X)^{2}$ by Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: What is $M$ here?

Comment: I am confused about where you used Holder and Chebyshev. Also how do you know the first term doesn't exceed $E(X_n-X)^2/M$?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is correct. Because my book teaches Fatou and Chebyshev and Cauchy-Schwarz and Dominated Convergence in the chapter.. Just having trouble to understand the solution now.

Comment: At the end I have explained how I got the bound for the first term.

Comment: Sorry if it is silly question but how do we go from $P(|X_n - X| > M) \leq E(X_n - X)/M^2$ to the first term not exceeding $E(X_n - X)/M$? I do not see it. I don't really know what $M$ is either

Comment: You have to apply this after applying Holder's inequality.

Comment: @joseph Holder's inequality/C-S inequality gives $EUV \leq \sqrt {EU^{2}}\sqrt {EV^{2}}$. Apply this with $U=X_n-X, V=I_{|X_n-X| >M}$. Note that $EV^{2}=P(|X_n-X| >M)$.  To get a bound for $P(|X_n-X| >M)$ use Chebyshev's inequality which gives $P(|X_n-X| >M)=P(|X_n-X|^{2} >M^{2})\leq \frac 1 {M^{2}} E(X_n-X)^{2}$. Now put this bound in previous inequality.